# How to change prop checked and trigg the onchange event of the same input?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have something like 
`<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" onchange="alert('HELLO!')"/>` and, in other place, other event do `$('#ck1').prop('checked',false)`, but, it not triggs the onchange event (!), that is, not do the `alert()`.

---

NOTE1: it is a question about jQuery concepts or tools, not exactly a "how to"... Because, strictly as set as above we can say "change your code!", to something like `<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" onchange="doAlert()"/>` and do a sequence, `$('#ck1').prop('checked',false); doAlert();`.

NOTE2 (edit after @ArturFilipiak deleted first good answer): the use of  `$('#ck1').prop('checked',false).trigger('change')` produced a side-effect, it triggers twice... I will build a jsfiddle later with something more simple tham by original big/complex code... (EDIT: the twice was a side-effect of my big code!). 
So: [the SOLUTION IS HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049945/287948), but the main contribution was from @ArturFilipiak, them I accepted his answer.

Comment: Could you please post a short  but complete code example of your issue? These two snippets might lead to wrong conclusions...

Comment: can you pls create fiddle ? with code example?

Comment: Just delete it, you can "undelete" it later again.

Comment: @arkascha and all, sorry, the answers was VERY FAST! and the interface does not allow delete...

Comment: All fine if you have your answer. We cannot say, since your question is not clear. Your decision :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT]** (confused radio with check-box)

Setting `.prop()` (or any other property/attribute) within script, does not trigger any events on that element.

You can trigger the event handler manualy with `.trigger()`.

Note, that it does not call the event itself, but the handler attached to this event and will not rely on the actual `:checked` state. Therefore you have to trigger the handler conditionally (checking if the actual `:checked` state is different than desired one)

> Any event handlers attached with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method. A call to `.trigger()` executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

---

Using your `onchange` attribute:

`<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" onchange="alert('HELLO!')"/>`

```
someFunction(){
    // trigger onchange only if the checkbox is actually checked:
    !$('#chk1').is(':checked') || $('#chk1').prop('checked',false).trigger('onchange');
}
someFunction();
```

Or setting `.change()` in jQuery:

```
$('#ck1').change(function(){
    alert('HELLO!');
});

someFunction(){
    // trigger change only if the checkbox is actually checked:
    !$('#chk1').is(':checked') || $('#chk1').prop('checked',false).trigger('change');
}
someFunction();
```

Comment: I must to test but seems the answer!

Comment: PS: good discussion and good workarounds. About my "to later explained problem", I must do the `someFunction()` every time ([in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z0q9vvu/1/) it is an `alert(RAMDOM)`) when checkbox changes (checked or not)... So, the condition is not necessary. Your first post, with `$('#ck1').prop('checked',false).trigger('change')`, was good (!). The main problem with the use of trigger, when it triggering an AJAX-onChange for example, is to avoid the event twice.

Comment: @PeterKrauss , I would need to see an example of how you use that in AJAX. Your demo seems to work perfect (no double alerts). Moreover, the `.trigger()` itself has surely nothing to that issue, as it always trigger a single handler (not the event). The issue is somewhere else in your code, but I can't really say what it could be without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `jQuery` checkBox `change` event.

```
$("#chk1").change(function(){
    alert($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rykqhmwf/)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry my delay in [show more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29049945/287948).

Answer (score 1):

you can use .when to check is your property set was compelete.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

eg.

```
$.when($('#ck1').prop('checked',false)).done(function( x ) {
   // callback
   doAlert();
});
```

but i perefer if you use jquery .. do in jquery what you can because it will give to you more effective tools

Comment: Thanks, the use of when/done is a good clue... Sorry my delay in [show more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29049945/287948).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, see comments about my problem to simplify and express a complete  example in the question.

Here is the problem and the solution(!): http://jsfiddle.net/7z0q9vvu/1/

---

### Problem with jQuery (bug?)

The change by `$('#chk1').prop('checked',newVal)` not trigg the onChange event.

### ... workaround (or effective solution)

```
   $('#chk1').prop('checked',false).trigger('change');
```

### CAUTION

That was my other problem: as the context in which you are using `.trigger('change')` you can make onChange event twice (!).

Comment: There's no "bug" in jQuery - see my answer. Events are not triggered when you modify an element with script. Also note, that in your demo you call `tigger()` without checking the check-box actual state. So that `onchange` method is called even if chech-box new state is same as previous (`false`) . Therefore it acts more like `onclick`, not really `onchange` (as nothing has been actually changed)

Comment: Thanks @ArturFilipiak about your clues (the correct use of `.trigger()`!) and good explanations.  I can say that seems a jQuery's "bug" because this behaviour broked the interface logic:  the code do a change, user see a change, but the event OnChange "not see" (!).